# Why is the .apply function for the .style attribute in pandas.DataFrame not called/accessed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, panel

I have a funtion in my project, using pandas and Panel, which has a strange behaviour.

```
    def _filter_cluster_df(self, selected_items):
        def _highlight(row, mask_i):
            print("inside")
            return ['font-weight: bold;']*len(row) if mask_i else ['']*len(row)
        if not isinstance(selected_items, list):
            slogans= selected_items['items'].explode().unique()
            slogans_first_part = np.array([s.split('_')[0].strip() for s in slogans])
        else:
            slogans= list(set([s for sublist in selected_items for s in sublist]))
            slogans_first_part= [s.split('_')[0].strip() for s in slogans]
        mask= self.table.df['list_slogans'].isin(slogans_first_part)
        print("before")
        self.table.table.style.apply(lambda r: _highlight(r, mask.iloc[r.name]), axis=1)
        print("after")
        return
```

`self.table` is an object which has an attribute called `table` that is a Panel.Tabulator. The Tabulator widget exposes a `.style` attribute just like a pandas.DataFrame which lets the user apply custom styling using methods like `.apply`.
The behavior I would like to achieve is that, every time the function is called, its style is updated and the change is visible on the table.

I added the `print` for debugging purpose and I noticed the following actions:

- when the function is called for the first time (when the table is created), it seems to work well (the layout appears with the applied style), but the several `inside` (one for each row) are printed after the `before` and the `after` (as if something were behaving asynchronously).
- from the second call of `_filter_cluster_df` (it is a function also called by clicking on certain buttons), only the `before` and the `after` are printed (not the sequence `inside`) and the layout of the table remains unchanged (even if the `mask` changes) (the `_highlight` is not accessed).
  I am sure that the code which creates the `mask` works well.